# Why can i put my laptop to sleep without sudo myself in a terminal, but not in a cronjob

Tags: fedora, permissions, systemd, cron

I can just run systemctl suspend in my terminal without sudo, and my laptop goes to sleep.

However, when I want to make a crontab for the same user that previously ran the command just fine without sudo (me) this doesn't work, and I have to run sudo crontab -e instead of just crontab -e to generate the crontab.